# How do I retrieve value of attribute of li-element (React, javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I can retrieve the contents of an input element like:

```js
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      stateProperty: event.target.value
    });
  }
```

in a React class definition's render() method that looks like:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <input
      onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
```

Now how do I retrieve the value of attribute key of the li-element

```js
<li
  onClick={this.handleClick}
  key='value_to_retrieve'
   >
  Li content
</li>
```

with handleClick:

```js
  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
      stateProperty: event.target.value
    });
  }
```

This doesn't do the trick, so I need something instead of event.target.value, but what?

Edited:
Here's how the 'key' shows up in the React developer tool, so it's not a regular prop:
[image]

Comment: `<li>` doesn't have a `value`, that's only for user inputs. Structure elements have `innerHTML` and `textContent`.

Comment: If it's output as a regular attribute you can just `event.target.getAttribute('key')`

Comment: so with the li element being in the same render() method as the input element, how do I retrieve the value of attribute key in handleClick()? What do I put in place of event.target.value there?

Comment: replacing event.target.value with event.target.getAttribute('key') gives me a value of null for key in handleClick()

Comment: event.target.innerText gives me 'Li content' which is correct but I'm looking for the value of attribute key

Comment: Try using something other than `key` as I think that's "reserved" by React. I just checked my code and while you can add a key attribute to some JSX element, it _isn't_ available _inside_ the component that's called which is where your problem is.

Comment: For example: `<Tag key={tag.id} id={tag.id} txt={tag.txt} />;`. Here I've duplicated the `key` value in `id` which _can_ be accessed within the component.

Comment: yes but I need to acces the (reserved) key-value, which is not a regular property, see question edit

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple ways to do that:

Easiest would probably be to look at `event.target` but use `getAttribute`:

```
handleClick(event) {
  this.setState({
   stateProperty: event.target.getAttribute('keyName')
  });
}
```

Probably not the best option for this use-case, but you could also use a `ref`

```
<li
  onClick={this.handleClick}
  key='value_to_retrieve'
  ref={el => this.li = el}
   >
  Li content
</li>
```

Then you can reference `this.li.getAttribute('keyName')`.

```
handleClick(event) {
  this.setState({
   stateProperty: this.li.getAttribute('keyName')
  });
}
```

Comment: What should I fill in for 'keyName': 'key'?

Comment: ... in your second code example I mean
By now I found out that 
1. the key-attribite a. needs to be there because of 'warning' 'each element in an array needs to heve a key prop' but b. cannot be used for this (or nobody knows how)
2. I can choose from other valid HTML <li> element attributes (as long as they are not 'value' or 'type' (see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp)
3. as long as they are supported by React, see https://www.reactenlightenment.com/react-jsx/5.7.html

Is this correct?

Now, using 'id' as attribute, event.target.getAttribute('id') works in the eventHandler